# Accepting user input in MYSQL? Shell Script / Batch File

Tags: mysql, database, shell, user-input

Here is my issue. I have a set of SQL database queries that I am triggering using a shell script and a corresponding batch file with .sql extension. Some of my queries require some manual user input (As per request), which I have had no luck implementing in my script.

As of now, I take in the user input as a date through the shell script:

```
echo "Please specify the date in yyyy-mm-dd format: 'input;"
read input
mysql -u user -ppass < batch_file.sql
```

I would like to pass the variable `$input` to the batch file.

The batch file with the sql queries being executed looks something like this:

```
select count(*) as count from subscriptions 
where date_add(optin_date, interval 1 year) between "$input" 
and date(curdate()) 
and active = 1 
and stype = "domain";
```

Where `"$input"` is the variable passed down from the shell script.

Any ideas would bee appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try doing this using a *here-doc* in a script :

```
#!/bin/sh

echo "Please specify the date in yyyy-mm-dd format: 'input;"
read input
mysql -u user -ppass <<EOF
select count(*) as count from subscriptions 
where date_add(optin_date, interval 1 year) between "$input" 
and date(curdatE()) 
and active = 1 
and stype = "domain";
EOF
```

Another solution if you can't use the first solution for any reason :

```
echo "Please specify the date in yyyy-mm-dd format: 'input;"
read input
sed -i "s/\"\$input\"/$input/g" batch_file.sql
mysql -u user -ppass < batch_file.sql
```

Better use something like `%%PATTERN%%` instead of `$input` in SQL file for substitution if you prefer the second solution.

Comment: The first solution only allows for one command to be run at a time, hence the batch file. 

The second solution makes sense, but it isn't detecting the variable.

Comment: You can run here-docs in the background with `&` (fork), so you can run N instances of SQL batchs.

Comment: Also, just checked and the first solution doesn't work. The `$input` variable is not being recognized.

Comment: Nvm, got the first solution working. I would still prefer a batch-file solution, it doesn't make sense for me to run it in instances.

Comment: If you think that the answer is useful, you can 'upvote' it. You can 'accept' the reply too by clicking the outline of the `checkmark` (will be green), this way, people searching stackexchange website will known that the question is well answered. That's how stackechange websites works, thanks ;)

Comment: It's not fully answered yet. I will upvote it, I just want to play with the solution and see if I can make it work.

Also, I'm very aware of how stack-overflow works. There is a reason I didn't upvote.

Comment: What if you want to assign the results of the mysql to a variable?

Comment: @KenIngram : `var=$( <COMMAND EVEN IN MULTI LINES> )`

Comment: Ok. Cool. I also discovered --execute="<text>". I set the text to the SQL I want to execute.

Comment: Yes, or simply `-e`